# How different is the intent for Apache NiFi Stateless vs Apache NiFi MiNiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm looking at performing simple operations at scale (Data Extraction from files with Layout aware processing) the engine for which has a large startup time and the processing time on a file itself is in the order of a few minutes. Using a NiFi cluster (16+ nodes) for such processing results in the Apache NiFi cluster taking about 45 minutes for the cluster startup and being available (Deployment in Kubernetes). I was looking to see if Apache NiFi MiNiFi or Apache NiFi Stateless will be handy here to reduce the cluster startup time and also allow me to scale out the processing as required in an easier manner. Which of the two would be a better fit? I understand that MiNiFi itself is more for a data collection use case but was wondering if it still would fit my use case?

Answer (score 2):

**NiFi Stateless** is basically an alternate runtime for NiFI flows. It is lighweight and doesn't persist data between restarts (hence the name :)
I think the information listed here is quite comprehensive:

- https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-stateless/nifi-stateless-assembly/README.md
- https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/11/10/apache-nifi-stateless

**NiFi MiNiFi** is essentially a headless NiFi (doesn't support authoring flows) and has justa  subset of NARs. On the other hand supports the C2 protocol and can download flows that way.

Based on your description if you have a single source and destination and you are ok with state lost between restarts stateless seems to be a better fit.